# What encoding technique needs to be used on keywords containing special characters to fetch YouTube videos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to fetch YouTube videos for keyword 'Color&Co' but I'm unable to get similar response through YouTube API as compared to manually searching same keyword on youtube.com.

I have tried following encoding techniques to get response from YouTube API similar to manually searching on youtube.com:

keyword = 'Color&Co'

1. URI.encode(keyword)
2. CGI.escape(keyword)
3. ERB::Util.url_encode(keyword)
4. keyword.encode('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')
5. keyword.encode('iso-8859-1').force_encoding('utf-8')
6. keyword.force_encoding('iso-8859-1').encode('utf-8')

I'm expecting YouTube API to return response similar to searching same keywords with special characters on youtube.com.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to manually encode it?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a GET request to the endpoint documented here https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list and the search term is passed as the `q` query string, you only need to use standard query string encoding as for any url. Even works with emojis.

Thus: `...?q=Color%26Co`